# How to sum current month records in MySql, I had something wrong with my syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function getPaymentsByMonth()
{   
    return
    $this->db->select('sum(payment_grand) as grand')
                     ->where('MONTH(payment_date)', date('m'))
                     ->count_all_results('payments');
}
```

### Problem

In my main admin page, I want to count current month profit.

Comment: what is exact error?  or write return statement in after complete query

Comment: where is group By? Sum is aggregate function which works with groupBy.

Comment: yeap, but I cannot find how to do that

Comment: @RavshanAbdurasulov, have you tried using `group_by()`?

Comment: Mayank Vadiya, here showed 16 if I do with group by

Comment: @Grzegorz Adam Kowalski, I did with 'group by' it showed 16 overall columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getPaymentsByMonth()
  {  
      $sql = "SELECT SUM(`payment_grand`) AS grand FROM payments WHERE MONTH(`payment_date`)=MONTH( CURRENT_DATE )";
    $query= $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row('grand');
}
```

Comment: if you find his/her answer satisfying please mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will sum the records for all year, not the current years month. As the question states "How to sum current month ..." the correct query should be

```
SELECT SUM(`payment_grand`) AS grand FROM payments WHERE MONTH(`payment_date`)=MONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) AND YEAR(`payment_date`)=YEAR( CURRENT_DATE )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentMonth = date("Y-m");
"SELECT sum(payment_grand) as grand FROM tableName WHERE payment_date LIKE " . $currentMonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
public function getPaymentsByMonth()
{   
    return
    $this->db->where('MONTH(payment_date)', date('j'))
             ->count_all_results('payments');
}
```